# How do I embed a query in a modern web page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've found a query that should display a list of SharePoint sites a user has access to.

> (contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web) AND NOT WebTemplate:SPSPERS AND NOT WebTemplate:Group AND NOT WebTemplate:App AND NOT WebTemplate:AppCatalog AND NOT WebTemplate:PolicyCtr AND NOT WebTemplate:POINTPUBLISHINGHUB AND NOT WebTemplate:POINTPUBLISHINGTOPIC AND NOT WebTemplate:EDISC AND NOT */sites/app_* AND NOT *-my/* AND NOT */contentTypeHub AND NOT *-public*

The part I'm struggling with is how can I actually embed the above on a Modern page? I'm using SharePoint in 365.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP Modern Search Web Part to show content using Search.

https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/

Hope it will helpful to you.